# Matrix-valued ODE - nonsingularity of solution

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have a matrix-valued inhomogenous linear ODE

$X' = F(t)X + G(t)$, $X(0) = I_{n \times n}$,

$F(t),G(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$,

and the entries of $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions. What assumptions do I need on $F$ and $G$ to ensure that $X$ is invertible on a given interval $[0,T]$? If anyone could provide a reference on the topic, I'd appreciate it.

Edit: In one dimension, it's sufficient that $G$ is positive on $[0,T]$. Could something like this carry over to higher dimensions?

Comment: If $G=0$, then $X(t)$ will be invertible, since it is the state transition matrix for the 'unforced' equation. Otherwise, you might try looking at the topic of zeros in the control literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the associated equation for $\det X$. Using that

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \det X = \det X \operatorname{tr} (X^{-1} \frac{d}{dt}X) $$

we get that

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \det X = \det X \left[ \operatorname{tr} (X^{-1} F X) + \operatorname{tr} (X^{-1}G) \right] $$

The first term is okay, as $\operatorname{tr} (X^{-1}FX) = \operatorname{tr}(F)$. For the second term, you need to be able to effectively control $\operatorname{tr}\left( \operatorname{adj}(X)G\right)$. The direct analog of the positivity condition of one dimensions is that $\operatorname{tr}\left( \operatorname{adj}(X)G\right) \geq 0$. (Notice that in 1 dimension the matrix $\operatorname{adj}(X) = 1$ always.) This condition however requires some a priori control on the range of $X$: that $X$ has positive determinant is not sufficient to guarantee a sign on $\operatorname{tr}\left( \operatorname{adj}(X)G\right)$ for non-trivial $G$.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.